Powershell out-file -append silently skips a few rows when used inside foreach loop
I am trying to extract a representative sample of a 200MB csv file by writing the header and every 500th row to a new file for testers to use. My first attempt was knowingly sub-optimal but seemed valid for a 5 minute quick hack, as I relied on out-file -append to add each row matching the modulus condition to the destination file on network share, but what I found is that I had slightly fewer rows in the sample file than expected. Repeated runs produced slightly different numbers of rows in the destination file (expected 2014, actual ranged between 1992-2011).
I re-wrote the script to gather the results of the foreach into a variable and output once at the end. That worked as expected (2014 lines), but curious as to the cause of the failure. I know it's repeatedly opening/closing the destination file but I'd have expected it to report an error.
This is the original version of the script:
$destfile = "\\UNCSHARE\Folder\Export_Sample_$(get-date -Format "yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").txt"

$Original = get-content "\\UNCSHARE\Folder\200MB_Export_20231208_1545.txt"

[int64]$ln = 0
[int64]$SampleCount = 0

foreach ($line in $Original) {
    $ln++
    if ($ln -eq 1 -or $ln % 500 -eq 0) {
        $line | Out-File -FilePath $destfile -Append -ErrorAction Stop
        $SampleCount++
    }
}
write-host $SampleCount

(get-content $destfile).count 

The error does NOT occur if I use a location on my local hard drive for the destination file.
I checked the 2nd (correct output) version output against the first, and can see that the missing lines are irregularly spaced thoughout the file (e.g. missing lines at 56,359,368,405,600,700,702,788,854...).
I'm running this in PS Core 7.4.2 on a Windows 10 workstation joined to AD domain.
Edit: I've tried replacing the cmdlet with native API call
#$line | Out-File -FilePath $destfile -Append -ErrorAction Stop -Encoding utf8
[System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($destfile, "$line`n") 

but I still get a variable number of missing lines and no errors reported.
Edit2: Switched to Windows Powershell 5.1.19041.3803 and now I do get an error with the native API call (but not with Out-File).
Exception calling "AppendAllText" with "2" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 
'\\UNCSHARE\Export_sample20240424_164810.txt' because it is being used 
by another process."

On my system Get-Command Out-File returns



Version
PS Version




3.1.0.0
5.1


7.0.0.0
7.4.2



I've tested again in fresh shell sessions and the results remain consistent. Out-File doesn't report errors, whilst [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText does, but only in Windows Powershell.
Edit 3:
The replacement code block to avoid the issue (as suggested by @Santiago Squarzon) looks like this:
# Collect the line data in a variable
$Sample = foreach ($line in $Original) {
    $ln++
    if ($ln -eq 1 -or $ln % 500 -eq 0) {
        $line
        $SampleCount++
    }
# Single write to file  
$sample | Out-File -FilePath $destfile


Try changing encoding to utf8

If this is a network issue then you're already aware on the fix of the problem as you have stated, avoid opening and closing the stream / using -Append and try to write all information at once then check if this issue keeps coming

Thanks for comments: @jdweng - utf8 didn't change the result.

Thanks for comments: @SantiagoSquarzon - gathering lines in variable works, but I'm curious as to why I don't get errors if out-file is unable to successfully write the content to destination. Outside this specific example, I'm hoping for information on the reliability/robustness of the cmdlet. From other tools I've used I think I might have got a 'failed to open for write access' type error.

well yes, I agree, but also we from our side don't have a way to verify what you're saying is correct... what you can try if you think the cmdlet Out-File is at fault here is a direct API call using [System.IO.File]::AppendAllText($destfile, "$line`n") and see if the API fails / gives error. but the definitive solution to the problem is to write only once

Note that out-file can mix different encodings in the same file.

Thanks for comments: @SantiagoSquarzon - I get the same behaviour using the direct API call (this time 17 records missing on write to UNC, but 0 records missing on write to C:).  I still don't get any errors reported, though I've also added $ErrorActionPreference="stop".

so looking at the updates, I see that .net framework actually throws an error. does Out-File -Append also (in 5.1) ?

@SantiagoSquarzon Out-File -append didn't throw an error in 5.1.  I ran out of time to test today, but thinking I should be testing in fresh -noprofile sessions from the shells, as my initial findings were running in VSCode, and wondering if F8 to run selected code (without reloading the get-content variable) was not reliable.

yeah, i don't think you can get an answer to this question unless an actual developer of the .net team sees it :P this may be a bug in .net (core) not reporting the error when writing thru a network stream. you could maybe open an issue to the .net repo or pwsh repo but at least you know that the solution to the problem is to open and close the stream only once (writing the content all at once)

@SantiagoSquarzon  - thanks for your comments. Would you like to post your latest as an answer and I'll accept it. I'd also edit my question to include the gather and write once version of the script.

It is hard to determine the cause of this issue, I do agree that both, the cmdlet Out-File and the .NET API File.AppendAllText should both report a writing error or a failure to close / open the open the stream on your consecutive appending operations. As we have discovered later on, using the .NET API in PowerShell 5.1 (.NET Framework) does report a writing error due to a handle already taken on that file (likable cause of this could be that previous loop iteration failed to correctly close the file stream after appending), however, the .NET 8 API (PowerShell 7.4.2) as well as the cmdlet in both versions are failing to report this issue. My advise in this case would be to open an issue to the .NET repo: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues and / or an issue to the PowerShell repo: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues to seek an answer to this issue.
As for the solution to the problem, instead of appending to the file which leads to file stream opening and closing consecutively, it is far recommended to perform this writing operation only once. Also for such a big file as you have, for efficiency purposes,  I'd recommend you to use File.ReadLines instead of Get-Content.
You could also avoid the need to store the new content in memory (by assigning it to variable) by wrapping the loop expression in a scriptblock, this allows streaming from it when invoked and also allows piping it's output to Set-Content or Out-File as you want:
$destfile = "\\UNCSHARE\Folder\Export_Sample_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').txt"

& {
    try {
        $sourcefile = '\\UNCSHARE\Folder\200MB_Export_20231208_1545.txt'
        $reader = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($sourcefile)
        $null = $reader.MoveNext()
        # output the first line, we can avoid the `-or` condition here
        $reader.Current

        [int64] $ln = 1
        [int64] $SampleCount = 0

        foreach ($line in $reader) {
            if ($ln++ % 500 -eq 0) {
                $line
                $SampleCount++
            }
        }
        Write-Host $SampleCount
    }
    finally {
        # null conditional is pwsh 7 only
        # use `if ($reader) { $reader.Dispose() }`
        # for pwsh 5.1
        ${reader}?.Dispose()
    }
} | Out-File $destfile -ErrorAction Stop


From feedback in comments it seems that $reader.MoveNext() into $reader.Current is failing to get the first line of the file, suggesting another alternative using StreamReader instead. Performance with this method should be equally as good as with File.ReadLines and hopefully more reliable.
$destfile = "\\UNCSHARE\Folder\Export_Sample_$(Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd_HHmmss').txt"

& {
    try {
        $sourcefile = '\\UNCSHARE\Folder\200MB_Export_20231208_1545.txt'
        $reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($sourcefile)
        # output the first line, we can avoid the `-or` condition here
        $reader.ReadLine()

        [int64] $ln = 1
        [int64] $SampleCount = 0

        while (-not $reader.EndOfStream) {
            $line = $reader.ReadLine()
            if ($ln++ % 500 -eq 0) {
                $line
                $SampleCount++
            }
        }
        Write-Host $SampleCount
    }
    finally {
        # null conditional is pwsh 7 only
        # use `if ($reader) { $reader.Dispose() }`
        # for pwsh 5.1
        ${reader}?.Dispose()
    }
} | Out-File $destfile -ErrorAction Stop


Many thanks @Santiago for your high quality answer and suggested improvement, which is indeed much faster. The only issue that I'm having is that it doesn't write the header line to the output file. I haven't played with ReadLines in PS, and not quite sure how to fix that issue.

mmm weird, doesn't $reader = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($sourcefile) then $null = $reader.MoveNext() and lastly $reader.Current output the headers of your file? @AutumnalSigh

It appears to be null when I step through the code in VSCode. It works if I comment those 3 lines out  and revert to if ($ln -eq 1 -or $ln % 500 -eq 0)  and doesn't seem to have a noticeable performance impact to do so.

@AutumnalSigh i'm unsure why could this be, definitely related to reading a remote file. could you try the new snippet using StreamReader instead? hopefully should be more reliable

Yes, that works : ) Many thanks. I also looked briefly at StreamReader while I was trying to fix it myself, but hadn't implemented a version using it.  I'm very grateful for the time you've spent helping me, and have learned about much more than my original question's subject (e.g. invocation operator) so I can't thank you enough.

@AutumnalSigh glad the answer was helpful :) btw use the updated version (with while (-not $reader.EndOfStream) {...)

ticket  [link] (https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/21545) raised on Powershell GitHub
